# bash scripting basic string comparison

Tags: string, bash, scripting, comparison

I have a basic bash scripting question. The output of this script, I expected to be:

a
y
b
x
c
y

but instead, I get:

a
x
b
x
c
x

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
for foo in 'a' 'b' 'c'; do
    echo $foo;                                         
    if [ "$foo"=="b" ]; then                                                                        
        echo x;                                                                 
    else                                                                        
        echo y;                                                                 
    fi                                                                                                                                                        
done;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sheesh, go easy on that whitespace...

Comment: OK. I figured it out. Having spaces between the operator makes a difference. Argh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add spaces around the `==` operator, otherwise it gets parsed as the single token `a==b` (after expansion, for the first iteration).  This gets passed to the `test` builtin (for which `[` is an alternative name).  Since the single argument `a==b` is a non-empty string atom, it succeeds and exits with a status of 0, and the `then` branch gets executed.

Comment: Actually, it succeeds and the `then` branch is executed. With a single argument, `test` returns true if the argument is non-null, and `a==b` is a non-null string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for foo in 'a' 'b' 'c'; do
  echo "$foo";

  if [ "$foo" = 'b' ]; then
    echo 'x';
  else
    echo 'y';
  fi
done;
```

You use `=` for string comparisons in bash. Also, quote your `echo`'d strings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for foo in 'a' 'b' 'c'; do

    echo $foo;

    if [ $foo == "b" ]; then        # Make a note of the spaces
        echo "x";
    else
        echo "y";
    fi
done;
```

Regards,

Rohan Dsouza